# Mockito.When not working for custom RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring

I need to do testing for the following service. When I try to do Mockito.When for custom restTemplate I get the error "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);".

However, when I don't do when(env.getProperty("test1")).thenReturn("test"); I get the error "I/O error on POST request for "/null/Test/null": null;"

How to make test properly for such service ?

**Test class**

```
@InjectMocks
private AccountService _accountService;
@Mock
private RestTemplate _restTemplate;


@Test
public void shouldGetAccount_200()  {
//when(_accountService.getRestTemplate()).thenReturn(_restTemplate);

when(env.getProperty("test1")).thenReturn("test");
when(env.getProperty("test2")).thenReturn("2"); 
when(_restTemplate.exchange(eq(String.format("%s/Test/%s", env.getProperty("test1"), env.getProperty("test2")), _accId), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(), eq(TestRequest.class)))
        .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(_resp, HttpStatus.OK));
assertThat(_accountService.getAcc(_accId, "test", "test", "test")).isEqualTo(_resp);
}
```

**Service**

```
public IResponse getAcc(String accId, String sessionId, String apiKey, String userName) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, sessionId);
    headers.add("X-Forwarded-For", getIPAddress());
    headers.add("Authorization", String.format("PS-Auth key=%s; runas=%s;", apiKey, userName));
    HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    ResponseEntity<TestRequest> response;
    
    return restTemplate.exchange(String.format("%s/Test/%s", env.getProperty("test1"), env.getProperty("test2"))), accId),HttpMethod.GET, entity, TestRequest.class);
}

public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {

    SystemDefaultRoutePlanner routePlanner = new SystemDefaultRoutePlanner(ProxySelector.getDefault());
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
            .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptorList = restTemplate.getInterceptors();

    if (tracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor != null) {
        interceptorList.add(tracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor);
        interceptorList.add(traceLogClientHttpRequestInterceptor);
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptorList);
    }
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using when() you assign the behavior to the mock that Mockito creates for you. This mock, however, never gets used since your `getAcc()` method calls the `getRestTemplate` that always creates a new instance of RestTemplate.

The obvious solution here is to use the put the `getRestTemplate` method in your configuration class and use it as a bean factory, autowiring* the RestTemplate bean into your `AccountService`. Then your @InjectMocks annotation will work as expected and you'll see that the service under test does indeed use the provided mock object.

*remember, there's three ways you can inject a bean in Spring - using field injection, method injection or constructor. That's not difficult to look up online so, I'll just say that most use-cases are handled best using constructor injection:

```
@Autowired
public AccountService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

Secondly, you don't show this but I'm pretty sure that env variable in `getAcc` is some kind of environment variables holder and is also not injected into the service properly so it doesn't get mocked. I would generally recommend to stick to `@ConfigurationProperties` (and you could easily mock those), or at least look into MockEnvironment.

As an aside, I can't think of why a service should need a new RestTemplate instance every time, and creating the RestTemplate is definitely beyound the scope of `AccountService`, so moving that to configuration also improves your code's structure. As a bonus, you can reuse the same RestTemplate bean in other services should you need that.

Evetually you might want to add a layer of abstraction making a separate bean to take care of constructing the url and adding the necessary headers to the RestTemplate request, so that the `getAcc` method gets more readable.

Comment: Thanks Yevgeniy, the problem has been solved perfectly. The restTemplate is now being assigned correctly. I created custom @Bean configuration for getRestTemplate() method and added it as Autowired to service.

Comment: Happy to help; if you consider the question solved, you might want to mark the answer as the accepted solution.   
I'd also like to mention it's probably best to autowire via constructor, although that might depend on things beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: If you can show how you would like to pass this in the constructor, please do.  I'd be happy to learn about any improvements.

Comment: edited my answer to include an example of constructor injection